# problem with multilevel menu

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu on my page but there are some problem i.e when the dropdown appear and moved down to certain limit it will disappear as shown in image.
[image]

1 ) when the dropdown appear for Mobile App Development as shown in image and moved down to Black berry its work but when i move mouse pointer to Palm the menu disappeared.
css code is

```
/* menu styles */
```

## nav, #nav ul{

margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
position:relative;
line-height:1.5em; 
}

## nav a{

display:block;
padding:0px 5px;
border:1px solid #333;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
text-align: center;
background-color:#333;
width:80px;
}

## nav a:hover{

background-color:#fff;
color:#333;
}

## nav li{

float:left;
position:relative;
border-right: 1px solid white;
}

## nav ul {

position:absolute;
display:none;
width:12em;
top:1.5em;
}

## nav li ul a{

width:12em;
height:auto;
float:left;
}

## nav ul ul{

top:auto;
}

## nav li ul ul {

left:12em;
margin:0px 0 0 10px;
}

## nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{

display:none;
}

## nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{

display:block;
}

what should i do in css so that my menu will appear on my other div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify z-index in your css:

```
z-index : 100;
```